What switch should I use to wire the projector screen trigger?
I have a projector screen that supports dry connection to allow screen up and down through RJ-45 port. Please see the diagram. Pin 3 connected to pin 4 makes the screen go down. Pin 3 connected to pin 6 makes the screen go up.
I am able to connect wire 3+4 and wire 3+6 to get the screen up and down. What kind of switch can I use to connect wire 3 to either wire 4 or 6? A momentary contact is fine.

Are you looking for a wall switch, or?

Wall switch is preferred. Otherwise just a regular one is okay. My IR sensor for this projector screen stopped working. Thats why.

Do you need momentary switches or maintained contacts?

Momentary is fine.

a switch connects, or disconnects, two wires ... almost any switch will work, even just touching two bare wires together

As the linked diagram indicates 3+4+6 as "Stop", it becomes relevant to know what happens if you touch 3+4 together and disconnect them before the screen is fully down. Does the screen stop partway through, or does it continue till fully down?

If the screen control requires momentary contact for up or down, then a single-pole double-throw momentary switch with center off should get you going. Wire pin 3 5V ground to the center contact, and 4 & 6 to the other contacts. (Note that double-pole will also work, simply use only one pole, if single pole is not available.)
If the screen control allows constant connection for up or down, a standard 3-way wall switch should work: pin 3 to the common screw, and 4 & 6 to the traveler screws.
If you desire to have the ability to stop an up or down command part-way, apparently the diagram allows connecting up and down both at the same time. In this case, two push-button switches, with pin 3 attached to a contact to both switches, will work. Pin 4 attaches to the other contact on one switch, and pin 6 attaches to the other contact on the other switch. Press Pin 6's switch for up, pin 4's for down, and both together to stop the movement.
A regular switch plate will provide a box cover for the 3-way switch. A blank plate can be used to drill correct holes for the momentary center-off switch or the two push-button switch schemes.

By way of example, the Leviton 1256 is an SPDT center-off momentary switch in conventional toggle switch style. Model 5685-2 is the Decora version. Like the ordinary 3-way, these will fit in a normal junction box with a normal switch (or Decora) plate.
